# Can't start VSFTPD

Tags: linux, ftp, vsftpd

I cannot get my FTP server to start, I have checked by using top and it does not show up. When I use `sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart` I get this "Stopping FTP server: No /usr/sbin/vsftpd found running; none killed. vsftpd. Starting FTP server: vsftpd."

When I run `sudo vsftpd` I get this "500 OOPS: config file not owned by correct user, or not a file"

I tried `sudo chown michael /etc/vsftpd.conf` as when I run `sudo chown michael /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` I get the no such file error. But I still cannot start the server.

Am I asking this is the wrong place?

Answer (score 2):

root is suppose to own vsftpd.conf

```
sudo chown root /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

Then try starting the sevice again

Comment: After doing that I now get this error "Stopping FTP server: No /usr/sbin/vsftpd found running; none killed.
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/run/vsftpd/vsftpd.pid’: Permission denied"

Comment: A `restart` in most scripts performs a `stop` operation and then a `start` operation. If the process is not already running, you may get errors (like those you listed) when it tries to stop the service. Is the process running now?

Comment: No, I have tried just the start command, and the I try restart and have the same issue

Comment: Now I just get this error "Stopping FTP server: No /usr/sbin/vsftpd found running; none killed.
vsftpd."

Comment: What happens when you run `sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd start` ? If you see no output, you should at least be logging to /var/log/rcvsftp.log so you can check that file for information about the startup.